# Retrieve Wrong Data from Drop Down List MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm a beginner so please bear with me.

Basically, I'm trying to get the selected value from a drop down list, but the results are not what I expected.

When I change the brand, it's works for first time. But it's doesn't work for the second time. When come to third time change, it's works but with second value.

For example,

```
<select name="brand">  
    <option value="">-Select-</option>  
    <option value="1">Brand 1</option>  
    <option value="2">Brand 2</option>  
    <option value="3">Brand 3</option>  
</select>
```

1st time: select "brand 1" and save - result: "brand 1"
2nd time: select "brand 2" and save - result: "brand 1"
3rd time: select "brand 3" and save - result: "brand 2"

My code is shown below. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have been trying to figure this out for a few days.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit_button'])){
     $brand= $_POST['brand'];
     mysql_query("UPDATE project_brand_table SET brand_id='$brand' where project_id='".$_GET['sub_menu']."'");
} ?>

<html>
    <body>
    <?php $results=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brands_table order by brand_name ASC"); ?>

    <select name="brand">
        <option value="">-Select-</option>
        <?php while($page1 = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { ?> 
            <option value="<?php echo $page1['id'] ?>"><?php echo $page1['brand_name'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Warning: you are prone to sql-injections. Do not use msql_ functions as they are deprecated.
Use mysqli_ functions instead. 

Also, in your SELECT statement, you are escaping the $_GET variable the correct way, but you don't escape the $brand variable. Why? 

About the SELECTING: are you limiting your selection in any way? Do you want the last inserted brand or all of them? Please expand.

Comment: is your question, that your selected brand is not getting displayed??

Comment: @Adimeus , I'm trying to get the value from URL www.domainname.com/project_gallery_edit.php?main_menu=7&sub_menu=126 by using the $_GET['sub_menu'] to find which brand_id I'm gonna to update. So in project_brand_table table, my project_id is 126 and I'm gonna update my brand_id via the drop down list.

Comment: @Ronser ,nope. It's displayed but get the wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

your code as written is fine. Please tell us where are you getting `$_GET['sub_menu']` value. i think its getting wrong value thats why its updating wrong value. One thing please do that check value before updating database using `die();` function that

```
$brand= $_POST['brand'];
```

this `$brand` value is correct or not..

Comment: I'm getting the value from URL www.domainname.com/project_gallery_edit.php?main_menu=7&sub_menu=126. At the same time, I'm trying to check the $brand value by using echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$brand');</script>" before save into database. The alert value is wrong as what I mentioned above.

Comment: please check this:<?php if (isset($_POST['submit_button'])){
    echo  $brand= $_POST['brand'];
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$brand');</script>";
}
  ?>

Comment: <form action="" method="post">
<select name="brand">  
    <option value="">-Select-</option>  
    <option value="1">Brand 1</option>  
    <option value="2">Brand 2</option>  
    <option value="3">Brand 3</option>  
</select>  
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" />
</form>

Comment: Please try above code as demo .i used this at my end its giving me correct value. I hope it will help full to you. Let me know

Comment: Actually I tested this before, but the result still same. But just now I found the problem is from the other line of code. Because I wrote $brand= ($_POST['new_brand']=="") ? sanitize($_POST['brand']) : sanitize($_POST['new_brand']); for existing brand and new brand insertion. Anyway, thanks so much because you remind me again.

Answer (score 0):

**consider the below example**

1. first check the value in `$brand= $_POST['brand'];` then add a selected attribute to your options

and

```
<select class="sele" id="t10" name="occ" >      
        <option value=""  >-choose-</option>
        <option value="Student"         <?if($arr[7]=="Student")    echo 'selected="true"';?>       >Student</option>
        <option value="Self Employee"   <?if($arr[7]=="Self Employee") echo 'selected="true"'; ?>   >Self Employee</option>
        <option value="Business"        <?if($arr[7]=="Business") echo 'selected="true"'; ?>        >Business</option>
        <option value="Govt. employee"  <?if($arr[7]=="Govt. employee") echo 'selected="true"'; ?>  >Govt. employee</option>
        <option value="Farmer"          <?if($arr[7]=="Farmer") echo 'selected="true"'; ?>          >Farmer</option>
        <option value="Merchant"        <?if($arr[7]=="Merchant") echo 'selected="true"'; ?>        >Merchant</option>

</select>
```

in the above example i have used the if condition to check and display the content in the select box which matches the `$arr[7]`

hope this helps you.. comment for further changes...

Comment: thanks for your reply. I already found where is the problem. :)